# How to display special characters from MySQL database to html?

Tags: php, mysql, html-encode

I have a huge database with a lot of languages stored in. All data stored in utf8_unicode_ci and my database collation is utf8_unicode_ci and I use special php page to call the sql data
this is my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$date=$_POST['date'];//I get this information from ajax request
$server_root = "./";
if(file_exists("{$server_root}include-sql/mysql.class.php"))
{
    include_once("{$server_root}include-sql/mysql.class.php");
}
include_once("{$server_root}config.php");//database connection information
$db1;
$db1 = new db_mysql($conf['db_hostname'], $conf['db_username'], $conf['db_password'], $conf['db_name']);
$sql = $db1->query("select * from matches where match_date='$date'");
$i=0;
while($sql_results = $db1->fetch_array($sql))
{
    $match[$i]['tournament_id'] = $sql_results['tournament_id'];
    $match[$i]['id'] = $sql_results['id'];
    $match[$i]['match_id'] = $sql_results['match_id'];
    $match[$i]['match_date'] = $sql_results['match_date'];
    $match[$i]['match_time'] = $sql_results['match_time'];
    $match[$i]['match_status'] = $sql_results['match_status'];
    $match[$i]['match_venue'] = $sql_results['match_venue'];
    $match[$i]['venue_id'] = $sql_results['venue_id'];
    $match[$i]['static_id'] = $sql_results['static_id'];
    $match[$i]['match_week'] = $sql_results['match_week'];
    $match[$i]['localteam_name'] = $sql_results['localteam_name'];
    $match[$i]['localteam_score'] = $sql_results['localteam_score'];
    $match[$i]['localteam_ft_score'] = $sql_results['localteam_ft_score'];
    $match[$i]['localteam_et_score'] = $sql_results['localteam_et_score'];
    $match[$i]['localteam_pen_score'] = $sql_results['localteam_pen_score'];
    $match[$i]['localteam_id'] = $sql_results['localteam_id'];
    $match[$i]['visitorteam_name'] = $sql_results['visitorteam_name'];
    $match[$i]['visitorteam_score'] = $sql_results['visitorteam_score'];
    $match[$i]['visitorteam_ft_score'] = $sql_results['visitorteam_ft_score'];
    $match[$i]['visitorteam_et_score'] = $sql_results['visitorteam_et_score'];
    $match[$i]['visitorteam_pen_score'] = $sql_results['visitorteam_pen_score'];
    $match[$i]['visitorteam_id'] = $sql_results['visitorteam_id'];
    $match[$i]['halftime_score'] = $sql_results['halftime_score'];
    $match[$i]['stage_id'] = $sql_results['stage_id'];
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($match);//return json to my ajax function
?>
```

The problem is all special characters in mysql are not shown in html in browser or show null I wnat to know is there any thing I miss it here? how to show those character on my page

Comment: how does your json array look like??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting to MySQL:

```
$db1 = new db_mysql($conf['db_hostname'], $conf['db_username'], 
    $conf['db_password'], $conf['db_name']);

$db1->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) says:

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server... It also specifies the character set that the server should
>   use for sending results back to the client.